# numpy.outer without flatten

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix, numpy

$x$ is an $N \times M$ matrix.

$y$ is a $1 \times L$ vector.

I want to return "outer product" between $x$ and $y$, let's call it $z$.

```
z[n,m,l] = x[n,m] * y[l]
```

I could probably do this using `einsum`.

```
np.einsum("ij,k->ijk", x[:, :, k], y[:, k])
```

or `reshape` afterwards.

```
 np.outer(x[:, :, k], y).reshape((x.shape[0],x.shape[1],y.shape[0]))
```

But I'm thinking of doing this in `np.outer` only or something seems simpler, memory efficient.

Is there a way?

Comment: What does the `k` variable contain in your code examples?

Comment: also [cross-posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57032234/2452869) with an accepted answer

Answer (score 2):

I think [numpy.tensordot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) does what you need.

```py
import numpy as np

N=2
M=3
L=4

x=np.arange(N*M).reshape(N,M)
y=np.arange(L)
z=np.tensordot(x,y,axes=0)

print('x=',x)
print('y=',y)
print('z=',z)
```

```
x= [[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]]
y= [0 1 2 3]
z= [[[ 0  0  0  0]
  [ 0  1  2  3]
  [ 0  2  4  6]]

 [[ 0  3  6  9]
  [ 0  4  8 12]
  [ 0  5 10 15]]]
```